# Different NullValueHandling for serialization and deserialization in asp.net core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I'm trying to implement PATCH method using view models which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. That is why I want NullValueHandling to be NullValueHandling.Include for deserialization (so explicitly defined null values will hit setters and will be handled properly).

In the same time, I want to get rid of null values in GET methods output. So I need NullValueHandling to be NullValueHandling.Ignore during serialization.

Is there some way to achieve such results using standard mechanisms of asp.net core web app?

For now I'm using this code to initialize Json converter:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddMvc(...)
        .AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
            ...
        });
    ...
}
```

And can't find any way to specify null value handling separately for serialization and deserialization. That's why I have to use two separate models, one for GET requests with default serialization, and one for PATCH requests with [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)] attribute and custom get and set methods.

Any ideas how to solve the problem with only one model?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm currently looking for a solution to the problem described.